# Show $\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}\,\forall x\in(-1,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show $\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}\,\forall x\in(-1,1)$. Which value does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ take?

---

Now because I skipped forward in my (personal) textbook I know that I could tackle this using knowledge of the Maclaurin/Taylor series. However, it was not covered in the lecture (yet) and my mind is fixated on using Maclaurin/Taylor (which I'm not allowed to use)! Can anybody show me an alternate approach that I will probably feel very stupid for not seeing?

Comment: Can you differentiate both sides?

Comment: It's going to be rather difficult to help you if we don't know what is available for you to use. Or, indeed, what sort of course this is.

Comment: To clarify, is your question concerning $x\in(-1,1)$ or does it concern the special case of $x=-1$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A term by term integration to the Geometric Series $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\nolimits_{k=0}^{\infty }{{{x}^{k}}}$

Comment: "However, it was not covered in the lecture (yet) and my mind is fixated on using Maclaurin/Taylor (which I'm not allowed to use)!" -OP

Comment: @Ennar eh, Maclaurin/Taylor for the geometric series is pretty overkill anyhow. I'd expect the geometric series to be known without any of that.

Comment: OTOH some care may be needed for the term by term integration.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art, yes, geometric series is well known without Taylor, but as you've said, term by term integration is problematic.

Comment: it is valid in this case

Comment: Rabie, of course it is valid, but it's usually proved for general Taylor series which OP didn't want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}x^k$ which is a power series. The radius of convergence is calculated by $\frac{1}{R} = \limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{1}{k^{1/k}}| = 1$ and thus the series converges absolutely $\forall x\in (-1,1)$. Therefore we can differentiate the series termwise. I.e.

$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}x^k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k-1} = \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Thus,

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}x^k = -ln(1-x) \forall x \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: "However, it was not covered in the lecture (yet) and my mind is fixated on using Maclaurin/Taylor (which I'm not allowed to use)!" -OP

Answer (score 0):

Use the geometric series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^n =\frac{1}{1-x} \qquad \text{ for } x\in (-1,1)$$
We can integrate both sides:
$$\int\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^n\,dx=-\ln(1-x)$$
Because the geometric series converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$, we can exchange integral and summation:
\begin{align}
-\ln(1-x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \int x^n\,dx \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}
\end{align}

For your second questions, we can send $x \mapsto -x$ to find that

$$-\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n}$$
Letting $x\ \to 1^{-}$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-\ln 2$$

Comment: Nitpicks: You used indefinite integrals, assumed that $\int\sum=\sum\int$ for an infinite series, and that $\lim\sum=\sum\lim$ for the last line.

Comment: I wasn't being too rigorous so that I could help OP understand the steps. Also, I did mention in my post that we can interchange sum and integral because of uniform convergence.

Comment: Hm... sure. Not entirely sure how I feel about using uniform convergence where Taylor isn't allowed, but whatever floats your boat.